# Unable to insert file stream into SQL filetable using Dapper.NET

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dapper, dapper-extensions

I am using Dapper.NET as ORM layer in my project. I am trying to write WebApis for  file upload and download. However I am not able to get it working. I have already searched enough to look for help but I couldn't find any.

If I was simply using ADO.NET, I could have used SqlParameter of type VarBinary for the file stream. But Dapper.NET query parameters is just dynamic object. So following code fails to insert the record into filetable.

```
var fileStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

var streamId = Guid.NewGuid();
var fileName = streamId.ToString();

var sql = @"Insert into Attachments(stream_id, file_stream, name)
            Values(@streamId, @fileStream, @fileName)";

using (var db = new SqlConnection(AppConfig.ConnectionString))
{
    await db.ExecuteAsync(sql, new { streamId, fileStream, fileName);
}

fileStream.Close();
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The member fileStream of type System.IO.Stream
>   cannot be used as a parameter value

Has anyone done this or be aware of any dapper extension plugin I could use?

Comment: HOw is DDL of  your table?

Comment: DDL is pretty straight forward
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attachments]
 AS FILETABLE WITH (FileTable_Directory = 'AttachmentFiles', FileTable_Collate_Filename = database_default)]

You can find many example on how to setup file table directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the DynamicParameters class and specify the parameter's data type.
For the example I created a table TEST with a column called Stream VARBINARY(MAX)

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var fs = File.Open(Properties.Settings.Default.filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO TEST (Stream) VALUES (@fs)";

        var dParams = new DynamicParameters();
        dParams.Add("@fs", fs, DbType.Binary);

        connection.Execute(sql, dParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: HOW configure ***FILESTREAM*** in SQL Server?